# Is there a way to make obfuscated batch files from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to make obfuscated batch files from a batch file?.
Here is a obfuscator code, the file is called  **obfu.cmd**

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
if /i "%~x1" neq ".bat" if /i "%~x1" neq ".cmd" exit /b
for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)
>"temp.~b64" echo(//4mY2xzDQo=
certutil.exe -f -decode "temp.~b64" "%~n1o%~x1"
del "temp.~b64"
copy "%~n1o%~x1" /b + "%~1" /b
```

But the problem is that you need to drag and drop the batch file every time you need to obfuscate it.
I want **wincheck** code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" == "" echo f
if "%version%" == "" echo f
if "%version%" == "" echo f
if "%version%" == "" echo f
if "%version%" == "" echo f
goto check
endlocal
:: 6.3 Windows 8.1
:: 6.2 Windows 8
:: 6.1 Windows 7
:: 6.0 Windows Vista
:: 10.0 Windows 10
:check
if %version% == 6.3 goto win8.1
if %version% == 6.2 goto win8
if %version% == 6.1 goto win7
if %version% == 6.0 goto winv
if %version% == 10.0 goto win10
exit
:win10
cls
echo You are running windows 10!
pause
exit
:win8.1
cls
echo You are running windows 8.1!
pause
exit
:win8
cls
echo You are running windows 8!
pause
exit
:win7
cls
echo You are running windows 7!
pause
exit
:winv
cls
echo You are running windows vista!
pause
exit
```

To be converted into **test.bat** *obfuscated* by the file called **obfu.cmd**.

So to summarise the **wincheck** batch code lives inside **obfu.cmd** and when I run *obfu.cmd* it creates a file called **test.bat** that is *obfuscated*.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You appear to have posted some code, and asked a question, but not explained how the two of them are related, or where `test.bat` becomes part of it. This site helps you to fix a specific issue with your provided code, unfortunately you've not indicated that there is an issue with that code, or what that issue is. If the code you've provided is not exhibiting an issue, your question becomes an off topic code request. Please edit your question to bring it up to that standards expected, based upon the content of [ask], and its contained sub-links; thank you.

Comment: You clearly took this code from a thread on Dostips.com. There are a couple of solutions in that thread. I would implore you to look at [Dave Benham's solution]( https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7990&start=15#p53278) in that thread.

Comment: I would also say that the version code you're using is technically not accurate, it relies upon detecting the version of Windows that the running `cmd.exe` executable was designed for, not the Operating System version upon which it is running. Whilst it will be likely that those two things are the same in the majority of cases, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Your only real option without blowing up the entire script and making it super complicated would be to hardcore which bat file gets obfuscated when you execute the obfuscate batch file. Which will also require you to remove several lines of code from the existing batch file.

Comment: You are taking a really super easy to use tool and making it overly complicated.

Comment: Whenever I see a batch file that tries to hide what it does, I delete it. No way, I run such a script on one of my systems. Mostly I don't even bother to find out what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but yes.
Create a folder called ofdata.
In it, make a file called ofv.bat.
Type this:

```
@echo off
set rxcxa=a
```

Say you wanted to start google but not make your code visible.
Now in your original script, you can type:

```
call ofdata\ofv.bat

st%rxcxa%rt https://www.google.com
```

And it would work.
You must have the call command in every file you want to obfuscate.
You can even go to the extreme and try something like this:

```
set rrcr=s
set rrac=t
set cazz=a
set rcct=r
set site=https://www.google.com
```

And then
type the call statement (call ofdata\ofv.bat)
and

```
%rrcr%%rrac%%cazz%%rcct%%rrac% %site% and it would open google.
```

You can even make variables with the alphabet!
Finally, open cmd and type cd yourdirectory
Then type cd ofdata
Then attrib +h ofv.bat /s /h
Just trust me